# Does DPO update the weights in the same way that LORA/Fine-Tuining does?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, training, large-language-models, fine-tuning, training-datasets

I've been working on making a conversational customer service fine-tune for the past couple months and now I am looking to improve its failure recovery.

For example, If the agent makes a mistake, how do I train it to recover from the mistake without training it to make the mistake in the first place. The training sample needs to include the agent causing the failure in order to recover, but then am I just training the model to make the failure in the first place?

I've currently been keeping any training samples that contain the agent making a mistake out of the dataset in fear of it just training the agent to make the mistake.

I thought DPO might be a solution to this, where you have a sample with a mistake, and then the chosen/rejected categories contain a bad retry and a good retry at the call. But I am concerned that DPO might just continue training the model to make the mistake in the first place and then recover from it.

Anyone have any suggestions?